# Finding out rails' test coverage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-coverage

I've just seen this issue on rails' issue tracker:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2667

And I'd like to find out which parts of the code aren't covered. I couldn't find a coverage tool into the Rakefiles, and searching for it is a bit frustrating, since it returns far more results about test coverage on your rails app than test coverage of the framework itself.

Has anybody set up a code coverage tool? Is there any documentation on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

[Rcov](https://github.com/relevance/rcov) (or [SimpleCov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) for 1.9) is the standard tool for Ruby code coverage. It should be fairly straightforward to get one of these to run the rails tests.

Comment: Could you please show me? The README says to add to the test_helper.rb, but rails' tests have none. Also, if I try to create and include in a couple of tests, I keep getting 0% coverage. So, it isn't being straightforward for me so far...

Comment: I run bundle exec rake spec:rcov